# Subcollection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't create a document in a non existing subcollection.

I have a collection users, with a document that has the userId as Id.
In this document I want a subcollection orders

the orders subcollection is not created yet. But you cant create empty subcollections.

So I do this:

```
const OrderID = 1; //just for testing
const ref = doc(
        db,
        "users",
        getAuth().currentUser.uid,
        "orders",
        OrderID
      );
```

But that does not work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok found it
OrderID can't be a number. It must be a string. The error I got did not tell me that. It complained about an out of range function.....

```
const OrderID = 1; //just for testing
const ref = doc(
        db,
        "users",
        getAuth().currentUser.uid,
        "orders",
        OrderID.toString()
      );
```